# How to make an exception in jquery to show element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a scrolltop method to hide/show my site logo when scrolled to a certain point. My navbar sticks to my screen when scrolled past the header. The header becomes the menu logo when scrolled past a certain point.

The problem is that I have hidden the header for mobiles, so the logo doesn't appear in the menu until I am scrolled halfway down the page!

How do I make an exception to show the logo constantly in the menu for a  certain window size? I.E. For tablets/mobiles.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(this).scrollTop()>275)
         {
            $('.navbar-left').fadeIn();
         }
        else
         {
          $('.navbar-left').fadeOut();
         }
     });
```

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/qlOqM

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Arabella Hill</title>
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/logo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9be29f1b6e.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container-fluid" id="header">
   <div class="page-header" class="img-responsive" id="main-logo">
      <img src="img/arabella.jpg" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
     <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="img/arabelltest.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</li>
            <li><a href="#">About</li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/forest.jpg" alt="forest" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/snowtiger.jpg" alt="meow" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/tiger.jpg" alt="meowwww!" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
     </div>
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
     </a>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="first-section" class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/forestbeautiful.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/beautiful.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="second-section" class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">
      <br >
        <p class="text-center">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean suscipit, neque eget faucibus bibendum, ligula diam gravida risus, sed faucibus felis velit gravida tellus. Phasellus vitae tempor ante, in eleifend eros. Morbi eu felis placerat, convallis orci vitae, rutrum nulla. Integer sed est euismod, tristique diam tincidunt, faucibus ex. Aliquam dui odio, fringilla sit amet nulla eget, vehicula semper ante. Suspendisse commodo felis orci, non ullamcorper ex faucibus ut. Fusce tempus scelerisque justo, pharetra efficitur risus porttitor quis. Vestibulum et tellus ligula.

                Sed molestie iaculis massa, nec ornare justo vehicula ac. Aliquam laoreet nisl volutpat sem sodales vehicula. Donec et porta sem. Vivamus aliquam facilisis ipsum sit amet rutrum. Aliquam lobortis interdum auctor. Aliquam ut vulputate dui. Integer eu blandit erat. Etiam quam ligula, porttitor in porta sit amet, sodales quis magna. Mauris non gravida arcu, id imperdiet metus. Mauris eu viverra justo, quis pretium turpis.

                Mauris laoreet ante et elementum mollis. Nunc tempor nisi id facilisis porttitor. Integer ante metus, ullamcorper at egestas a, vehicula in ligula. Donec sed lacus est. Aenean blandit tincidunt dolor nec lacinia. Praesent finibus turpis ultrices, semper libero at, semper sapien. Morbi molestie ex congue risus porttitor, nec feugiat orci pulvinar.

        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="module parallax parallax-1">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Services</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin hendrerit vitae purus quis imperdiet. Aenean elementum porta erat, at posuere est elementum non. Sed ut lorem eu ante ornare tristique quis eu odio. Proin nibh ligula, semper eget mauris nec, egestas mattis libero. Vestibulum auctor tellus vel augue rutrum lacinia. Nunc nec felis velit. Nulla augue magna, vehicula in convallis sed, pretium nec odio. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis a mauris vestibulum, ornare elit ac, consectetur sem. Pellentesque sem neque, ultricies nec lobortis eget, pellentesque nec lorem. Phasellus feugiat varius nisl, vel efficitur eros ultrices et. Sed sollicitudin, massa sit amet finibus eleifend, leo magna rhoncus sem, suscipit lacinia nulla mauris nec nibh. Aliquam ut massa id justo ullamcorper dictum vel rhoncus urna.

                </p>
  </div>
</section>
</div>


<section class="module parallax parallax-2">
  <div class="container" class="img-responsive">
    <h1>Gardens</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="container" id="gallery-container">
  <div class="row" id="gallery-row">
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4" >
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

<div class="content">
</div>
    <footer id="myFooter">
        <div class="container">
        <p class="footer-copyright">© 2017 Copyright Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-social">
            <a href="#" class="social-icons"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="social-icons"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="social-icons"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>




    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default

{background-color: #fbfbfb;margin-bottom: 0px;}

.navbar-fixed {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#brandlogo {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
.page-header {

  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}


body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
.container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}


.img-responsive {

  max-width: 40%;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: white;
}

.jumbotron img{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}

.navbar {


}

.scroll-top {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   right:6%;
   z-index:100;
   background: #f2f3f2;
   font-size:24px;
   border-top-left-radius:3px;
   border-top-right-radius:3px;
}
.scroll-top a:link,.scroll-top a:visited {
  color:#222;
} 

.navbar-nav {margin-left: 50px;margin-top: -5px;}

#main-logo > img {

  margin: auto;
}
#test {

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.col-lg-12 {
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#services{

  height: 500px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.img-circle {

  border-radius: 50%;
}

.row img {

  max-width: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container-fluid {

  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#first-section {

  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#first-section .row .col-sm-4 {

  height: 350px;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  height: 337px;

}

#first-section .row img {

padding: 0;
height: 333px;

}


#gallery-row {

  margin-top: 15px;
}


.col-md-4 img {

  height: 333px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#second-section {

  height: 600px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#second-section > div > p {

  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}

#second-section .container {

  margin-top: 140px;
}

#test {

  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}

.col-xxs-12 {

  padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {

    font-size: 11px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {

.col-xs-6 {

    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px ) {

  #second-section > div > p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

   section.module p:last-child{
    font-size: 14px;
   }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px ) {

  #header {

    display: none;
  }
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav {/* margin-left: -7px; */margin-right: 170px;background-color: #fff;padding: 0;padding-right: 50p;/* margin-bottom: -2px; *//* margin-bottom: -10px; */}

div.navbar-header {

  background-color: white;
}

img.img-responsive {

  height: 267px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: -500px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 270px;

}

#first-section .row .col-md-4 {

   height: 274px;
}

.text-center p {

  font-size: 1px;
}

section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
  height: 600px;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover !important; 
  margin-top: -30px;
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/snowtiger.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position:center;
  background-size: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto2s;


}

section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image: url("../img/tiger.jpg");

}

section {

  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#myFooter{
    padding-top:32px;
}

#myFooter .container{
    text-align: center;
}

#myFooter .footer-copyright{
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
}

#myFooter ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

#myFooter a{
    color: #282b2d;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#myFooter li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    line-height: 2;
}

#myFooter .footer-social{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

#myFooter .fa{
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #d0d0d0;
    border-radius: 51%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 43px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition:color 0.2s;
}

#myFooter .fa-facebook:hover{
   color: #2b55ff;
}

#myFooter .fa-facebook:focus{
    color: #2b55ff; 
}

#myFooter .fa-google-plus:hover{
    color:red;
}

#myFooter .fa-google-plus:focus{
    color:red;
}

#myFooter .fa-twitter:hover{
    color: #00aced;

}

#myFooter .fa-twitter:focus{
    color:#00aced;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I did not read every line of code you got but it looks like `navbar-fixed` is controlling the styling, all you need to do is define this class for `width > xxx` where xxx is your cutoff for tablet size. So in `width < xxx` the class simply does not do anything. Or define it differently so you are showing what you need

Comment: The problem is I don't code javascript.

Comment: How do I only render the javascript file at a certain width?

Comment: My comment was towards CSS not js, the width check is simply a media query. Meaning, that class is going to get added the same as before but as long as you define the css class accordingly then everything should work

Comment: But in the javascript file, I have hidden/shown my website logo at a certain point on the scroll. I want that to change when the width of the browser is at the size of a mobile/tablet.

Comment: I.E. I need the website logo to always be shown on a tablet, phone.

Comment: Because at the moment it isn't showing until I scroll down at a certain point. Because I have hidden the header for phones/tablets, it only appears when I have half way down the page.

Comment: Your js in the question, it ONLY add/removes `navbar-fixed` css class. Which means that css class controls everything. If you don't know how to code css and js then I don't see why you are working on this. You can also edit previous comment instead of posting new ones

Comment: Sorry if this is complicated to understand, but I have added a bootsnipp file in my post. I know how to code css but not javascript..

Comment: I understand this fully, but you are not getting it lol

Comment: Ah, it is my css class which is controlling everything, not the javascript. This means I just only need to make an @media query from the css. You can make an answer, happy to mark it as correct..

Comment: Yes, if you want this menu to be sticky for say `width < 768px` then you just need to add the css rules of `navbar-fixed` to `#nav` in the media query and you are done. If that's not the intention then I am sure you can figure out what I mean by now

Comment: I am so sorry, I added the wrong file. I am very tired. Does this javascript file still apply with the solution?

Comment: This logo of yours, it's for a navbar on the left? not the page nav? This is a little different, but it is possible to override in css if you don't know any js

Comment: Yes, it is the logo on the left in the menu.

Comment: but as you can see the class is defined in the HTML.

Comment: As I mentioned before you can use css to override the js if you cannot update the js at all. You will need to use `!important` in your css. For which rule you need to override, I suggest you inspect the element when it is faded out

Comment: Is there an elseif statement in javascript where we can cancel the scrolltop method at a certain screensize.

Comment: The logo would then always appear in the menu and I wouldn't have to scrolldown for it to appear.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!